# make doesn't find rules to make target (newbie on manual makefile generation)

Tags: c, makefile, target, rule

I have the following makefile that I tried to construct out of a tutorial. Then I (thought) i added the necessary sources in order to fit it for my code.. but it doesn't find the target. I think It may have to do with the folder structure of the sources, but I can't figure it out.

```
SVN_REV=(svnversion -cn | sed -e 's/.*://' -e 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' | grep '[0-9]')

DEBUG_OPTS:=-g  -DSVN_REV \
            -DDEBUG_MODE \
            -UTIME_MODE \
            -UREADFROMFILE 

CFLAGS:=$(DEBUG_OPTS) -c -Wall 
LDFLAGS:=$(DEBUG_OPTS) -lpthread 

EXECUTABLE:=fw_board
COMPILER:=arm-linux-gcc
```

(makefile cont'd below, there are the src files locations as seen from the TOPDIR)

```
SOURCES:=main_process/main.c \
      ezxml/ezxml.c \
      info_file_parser/info_file_parser.c \
      info_file_parser/array_management.c \
      info_file_parser/protocol_file_parser.c \
      info_file_parser/sequence_file_parser.c \
      info_file_parser/topology_file_parser.c \
      seq_exec_module/seq_execution.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/pca950x.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/ltc2495.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/ltc2609.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/temperature_uc.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/pcf8574.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/stepper_motor_control.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/test_functions.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/stepper_pca.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/stepper_atmega.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/general_i2c.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/zx_mbd_pwr.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/virtual_switch_handler.c \
      i2c_device_drivers/pressure_sensor_ASDXAV030PG7A5.c \
      hashing/ConfigData.c \
      hashing/Hash.c \
      hashing/LinkedList.c \
      init_file_parser/init_file_parser.c \
      usb_communication/serial_comm.c \
      protocol_parser/protocol_parser.c 


BINDIR:=bin
OBJDIR:=.obj
OBJECTS:=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o))

.PHONY: all
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)
    @echo all_start
```

this is the linking stage

```
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) | $(BINDIR)
    @echo link
    $(COMPILER) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $(BINDIR)/$@
```

and the compilation stage. but main.c can't be located as you'll see

```
$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJDIR)
    @echo compile
    $(COMPILER) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir $(BINDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo removing_files
    rm -rf $(OBJECTS) $(BINDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)
```

running make returns the following:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `main_process/main.c', needed by `all'.  Stop.
```

Comment: What does `$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJDIR)` mean? Two `:` in the same prerequisites line? I cannot find that in the docs.

Comment: @rodrigo: The GNU make manual mentions it in  http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Syntax

Comment: @thiton I read that. I find the double-colon and the colon-and-semicolon, but the 2-separated-colons I cannot see anywhere.

Comment: Oh, ack, sorry, I thought it was right at the start, but it is actually in section "4.12.1 Syntax of Static Pattern Rules"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't list the sources as a dependency of all.

all: depends on $(EXECUTABLE). Incidentally, the echo will only get output (if at all) AFTER $(EXECUTABLE) has been built.

$(EXECUTABLE): depends on $(OBJECTS)

I'm not quite sure what the syntax on your $(OBJECTS) rule is doing, but there is no need to have an explicit rule on $(OBJECTS). Just having the $(OBJECTS) list all the object files, and then having a rule to generate them from the C files is sufficient.

With all those rules, "all:" is implictly dependant on the sources anyway. Also, "all:" is a "phony" rule, so will rebuild all dependencies every time anyway.

The path main_process/main.c needs to exist relative to the directory that contains the makefile.

Fix all that and you should be good to go.

Comment: hello there I have some questions.
1. you wonder about this:
    $(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c | $(OBJDIR)

Comment: It basically was the only thing that worked.I give name to the target (ie a list of objects to be compiled) so that it can be called by the @(EXECUTABLE) rule. The rule couldn't be missing ofcourse. 
after the 1st ':' I declare the dependencies of the object files (the output/target) from the .c counterparts. I couldn't omit the object targets since i'd have problem with placing the .o files in a separate object directory...

Comment: after the '|' I declare dependencies that need not be run ncessarily (haven't quite grasped the gnu tutorial explanation. Basically the OBJDIR will be created if it doesn't exist..

Comment: you also talk about all being phony and that all the dependencies will be run again but what do you suggest I alter?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where exactly your make went wrong without a lot of information about your build environment, but your best bets are:

1. Use make -d to show you where things went wrong. If you don't use implicit rules, make -rd is more concise.
2. Use automake to avoid writing a Makefile at all.

In principle, if there is such a thing as the file main_process/main.c, it should be compiled. Have you tried an ls with the exact same name?

Comment: yup, it was stupidity in the end.
it was main_process.c instead of main.c
ls -l actually solved the mystery. thank you